# Why won't this jquery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want it so that when a person presses the enter button, it would execute my function.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    $('textmoney').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        moneyFunction();
    }
})
    </script>
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: *Why won't this work?* can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: What happens, doesn't work does not explain much. Do you get console error's, what happens when you console.log('test') it or use debugger;

Comment: if `textmoney` is a class use.. `$('.textmoney')` and if id then `$('#textmoney')`..

Comment: Not a very clear question

Answer (score 3):

You are missing either ID or class selector while attaching the event.

If `textmoney` is class

```
$('.textmoney').keydown(function (e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13){
    moneyFunction();
}});
```

If `textmoney` is ID

```
$('#textmoney').keydown(function (e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13){
   moneyFunction();
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing either id or class in jQuery selector,
so it should be like `$('#textmoney')` or `$('.textmoney')`depending on your selector.

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, you are missing a ID or class selector before `textmoney`. It should be `#textmoney` or `.textmoney`.

But you are also inserting your script inside the script tag loading jQuery. You can't do that. It is either you load a source or you run the code between the tag. The `src` is always prioritized so your code will never be run.

Separate the two, use 2 script tags :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#textmoney').keydown(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            moneyFunction();
        }
    });
</script>
```